# Scaffold bottomNavigationBar overlapping body content. How to prevent it

Tags: flutter

I want to a dashboard with app bar and bottom navigation bar. But when i add listview or pageview in body(Scaffold) the content is overlapped with bottom navigation bar.

I have set the padding widget and aspect ratio widget but the content height vary in different screen size.

```
BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,

        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.chat_bubble),
            title: new TextView(
              'Conversations',
              size: 16.0,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.dashboard),
            title: new TextView(
              'Matchboard',
              size: 16.0,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: TextView(
                'Match-o-Meter',
                size: 20.0,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ))
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: IndexedStack(index: _currentIndex, children: <Widget>[
              CouplingMatches(),
              MatchBoard(),
              MoMPage(),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

I want the body content in between appbar and bottom navigation bar but i getting the result as:
[image: Dashboard]

i have scroll to down but content is overlapping with bottom navigation bar

Comment: any news ? did u find solution ?

Comment: @GirlWhoCode I think flutter fixed the solution. currently there is no overlapping in my UI.

Answer (score 12):

Wrap the body of your `Scaffold` in a `SafeArea` widget.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use these

```
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
```

Change the parameter until you don't get output and remembar it's a property of Scafflod.

Comment: bottomnavigationbar

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap your widget in body of the Scaffold with a container, and then provide the bottom padding to it:

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: kBottomNavigationBarHeight),
    child: //place your widget here...
);
```